# DialogFragment : NullPointerException (support library)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragment, android-support-library

I'm using the excellent [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) library to receive error reports from my apps.

I'm receiving a lot of reports from customers concerning an NPE in DialogFragment, but Im unable to reproduce it :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onActivityCreated(SourceFile:366)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:892)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1083)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1065)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(SourceFile:1844)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(SourceFile:519)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1133)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4475)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1929)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The NPE happens inside the **support library** (@line 366):

```
353    @Override
354    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           (...)
361        View view = getView();
362        if (view != null) {
363            if (view.getParent() != null) {
364                throw new IllegalStateException("DialogFragment can not be attached             to a container view");
365            }
366            mDialog.setContentView(view);
367        }
```

Im unable to reproduce the problem on any of my device (from 2.2 to 4.1.1). Since there's no reference to any of my code, is it a library bug?

Comment: Either your **view**  or  **mDialog** is not instanciated.

Comment: mDialog is a private instance inside the support library. If you read the stack trace carefully, none of my code is called yet when the NPE occurs!

Comment: from where are you calling the DialogFragment?

Comment: You said "none of my code is called yet when the NPE occurs!". That is the enough reason for NPE. I mean have you initialized mDialog earlier using mDialog.setContentView(view); in control-flow??

Comment: The control flow is fine, my DialogFragment is returning a view when onCreateView. Im unable to reproduce it here despite a lot of device/version. Here is the [library source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.java/#366).

Comment: It says it's nullPointerException in your code in your function at line 366. it's clearly mDialog not initialized.

Comment: @Kobor42 : the snippet is NOT mine, this is from the android support library (as stated). Thousands of customers so far, I'm not a newbie, I'm just unable to reproduce this NPE.

Comment: @nono240: did you ever figure out the root cause of this problem?

Comment: this happens when you rotate the screen while the dialog is visible.

Comment: I got one way to reproduce the same issue. When a dialog appeared in an app(let's call this app A), press Home key to push app A into background mode. Then you can launch other apps to consume memory to make app A be killed. After this, to launch app A again will trigger this crash. 
Obviously, because the background process of app A has been killed, most related objects are null.

Answer (score 11):

I have had to debug the same issue in a project.

Typically Dialog fragment is used as below

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  //Create custom dialog
  return dialog;
}
```

Try updating it to the following

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  //Create custom dialog
  if (dialog == null)
    super.setShowsDialog (false);

  return dialog;
}
```

This will prevent DialogFragment.onAtivityCreated() from executing methods on the null member variable mDialog.

Comment: I don't understand how this could have any effect... if "dialog" is created where your comment is, how could it possibly be null at the end of that method? You just instantiated it, it can't possibly be null.

Comment: Good question, In most cases you will create a dialog but there may be a case (such as the case above where an NPE is being thrown) where the dialog is not created. In that case you need to be sure the framework does not try to show the non-existent dialog.

Answer (score 9):

This is a relatively common crash that I've seen reported within StackOverflow, and it's due to the dialog not being created properly, causing mDialog to be null.  The brute force method I initially used to prevent the crash:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle arg0) {
    if (getDialog() == null ) {  // Returns mDialog
        // Tells DialogFragment to not use the fragment as a dialog, and so won't try to use mDialog
        setShowsDialog( false ); 
    } 
    super.onActivityCreated(arg0);  // Will now complete and not crash
```

}

While the above is probably better than a crash, this doesn't address the root cause of why the dialog failed to be created.  There could be many reasons for that and that's what needs to be debugged.

In my situation, I found that I needed to implement DialogFragment's onCreateDialog() *instead of* onCreateView() to properly create the dialog 100% of the time.  (onCreateView() almost always works to create the dialog, but I PROVED that there are reproducible corner cases where onCreateView() fails to work, causing mDialog to become null.  On the other hand, I always found that onCreateDialog() properly created DialogFragment's dialog.)

Comment: `and it's due to the dialog not being created properly, causing mDialog to be null`. How did you arrive at this? `onCreateDialog` is annotated with `@NonNull` return type.

Comment: "there are reproducible corner cases" - could you provide one please?

Comment: @cylon, You can see the comments in this question. One case to reproduce is the background process of the app is killed when the dialog appeared.Then launch the app  again.

Answer (score 2):

`DialogFragment.mDialog` can be null if `DialogFragment.dismiss()` is called before `onActivityCreated()` is called.

Comment: One way to "reproduce" it to call dismiss inside ```onViewCreated```

Answer (score 1):

I had the NPE.

But surrounding the `super.OnActivityCreated` with a `try/catch` did not help.

What did help was the removal of a static field that was left over from copying an example.
So, no static fields inside an overridden DialogFragment.

Comment: Can not confirm this solution I do not have any static fields but also get this crash sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not. This is the common error if the SetContentView crashes. setContentView calls the constructors of the Controls of your view. One throwed a nullPointerException.

Comment: Constructors are not called on setContentView.

Comment: setContentView inflates the resources - which calls for constructors. I don't know what it does with views. This error message is not that one however. My best bet for this problem is that you use threads. If a thread ended, then it's not freed but only after 60 secs. If restarted in that period of time all the variables remain the same, and I couldn't figure out what other bugs happen in these scenarios. But if you hold any pointers and call them, after a screenturn/back-front event some prestored Activity pointers could point to stub, and stuff. Do you use any custom activity handling?

Comment: No threads. IMO, there's something weird in the Fragment manager implementation. I ended up by overriding `onActivityCreated`, and surrounding `super.onActivityCreated`by a catch block.
And so far, no more customer complaining about unexpected force close.

Answer (score 0):

If you are overriding onCreateView(..) to instantiate the view of your DialogFragment you need to show it using a fragment transaction and put setShowsDialog to false to avoid this error. i.e:

```
            //Instantiate your DialogFragment and fragmentManager previously and then just do this:
            dialogFragment.setShowsDialog(false);
            FragmentTransaction fT = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fT.add(0, dialogFragment, TAG);
            fT.commit();
```