# Android Support v4 DialogFragment Crashing Application

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-support-library

I'm getting this exception from my error logs that my app sends when it crashes:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{<my activity>}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3553)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1233)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onActivityCreated(DialogFragment.java:368)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1486)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1877)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:552)
    at <my FragmentActivity wrapper>.onStart(BaseActivity.java:16)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1167)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2073)
    ... 12 more
```

I have been unable to reproduce it, and the logs leading up to this crash don't seem to indicate that any `DialogFragment` was shown. [This is the line in the support library that is causing the crash](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.java/#368)

Comment: Show code used to create and show the dialog please.

Comment: A NullPointerException seems to be causing your problems, please post your code, especially the part where the exception occurs so we can help you solve your problem.

Comment: `getActivity()` is returning `null`, which means that the `DialogFragment` is not attached to an `Activity`. Post the code where you are calling the `DialogFragment`.

Comment: I have around 5 possible `DialogFragment`s being shown. Neither the crash stacktrace, or my own logs give any indication as to which `DialogFragment` it is, so I can't really post code for it.

Comment: rotate the screen while your dialog is showing causes this, see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465932/android-support-dialogfragment-crashes-on-screen-rotation

Comment: I'm not sure that's my issue, but I will investigate further. Thanks!

Comment: @Niall I haven't seen this issue for the past few releases of the support library.

Answer (score 2):

mDialog is null, meaning that your dialog wasn't properly created.  I had the same situation where this would occur, but in very limited circumstances (nothing to do with screen rotation, but it was something I could reproduce 100% of the time), and it had to do with onCreateView() not properly creating the dialog, leading to the null mDialog.  onCreateView() can be used to create a dialog -- the Basic Dialog section of http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html even shows this -- but I proved that it is NOT always reliable.  However, in my crash scenario, I found that using onCreateDialog() instead of onCreateView() would always work, even though I was using the same layout and data that my onCreateView() was using.  So I changed my code to use onCreateDialog() when using the DialogFragment as a dialog and that solved the issue.  So that is one thing you may want to check.

If you want a brute force method to stop the crash (though the root cause of why mDialog is null would remain), you can use this code -- which I used successfully until I found the real issue above:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle arg0) {
    if (getDialog() == null ) {  // Returns mDialog
        // Tells DialogFragment to not use the fragment as a dialog, and so won't try to use mDialog
        setShowsDialog( false ); 
    } 
    super.onActivityCreated(arg0);  // Will now complete and not crash
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The answer here:
[DialogFragment : NullPointerException (support library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265611/dialogfragment-nullpointerexception-support-library)

Add this code:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog (Bundle savedInstanceState)

  //Create custom dialog
  if (dialog == null)
    super.setShowsDialog (false);

  return dialog;
}
```