# Android Support DialogFragment crashes on screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to switch my app to use dialog fragments but I get an application crash when rotating the screen while the dialog is visible. I can reproduce this in a very simple app described below. Create a new project in Android studio and add a DialogFragment like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .setMessage("Alert")
                            .setTitle("My Alert")
                            .create();
                    MyDialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
                    dialogFragment.setDialog(dialog);
                    dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");

                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedState);
        }
    }

    public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        private Dialog mDialog;

        public MyDialogFragment() {
            super();
            mDialog = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
            super.onCreate(state);
        }

        // Set the dialog to display
        public void setDialog(Dialog dialog) {
            mDialog = dialog;
        }

        // Return a Dialog to the DialogFragment.
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return mDialog;
        }
    }
}
```

Now run the app, and after the dialog shows up (1 second after loading), rotate the screen. Note that I only create the dialog on the initial onCreate above.

Here is the exception Im getting:

```
01-30 11:19:40.199  31986-31986/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testdialogs, PID: 31986
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testdialogs/com.example.testdialogs.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3758)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onActivityCreated(DialogFragment.java:368)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1508)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1884)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:566)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3758)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My gradle script looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

which is just the standard build script when you create a new project and uses the latest android support jar.

I can do setRetainInstance in the DialogFragment's onCreate method and then it doesn't crash, but the dialog gets dismissed on rotation. This is better than a crash obviously but not what I'm looking for.

I'm not really sure what the preferred way of using DialogFragments is but I got this idea from some sample code straight from google (for the google service sdk). I figured they knew what they were doing so I'd use the same concept.

Answer (score 4):

I solved such a problem via subclassing DialogFragment class and overriding next two lifecycle callback methods:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance()) {
        getDialog().setDismissMessage(null);
    }
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I hate to answer my own questions but I figured out the reason for the crash. I need to actually do the dialog creation in onCreateDialog of the DialogFragment rather than setting it from my Activity. Not exactly sure *why* this is the case. Perhaps on rotation the android system erases references tied to the old instance of the Activity. This isn't totally ideal but I can work with it by perhaps passing in the data used to create the dialog in

Here is the update code which works on rotation without crashing:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MyDialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
                    dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");

                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedState);
        }
    }

    public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        public MyDialogFragment() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
            super.onCreate(state);
        }


        // Return a Dialog to the DialogFragment.
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setMessage("Alert")
                        .setTitle("My Alert")
                        .create();
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the activity is first created, the `savedInstanceState` is null because it had no previous state to be saved. When the screen is rotated the activity is destroyed and the `onCreate(savedInstanceState)` is called again with some states saved (like your `DialogFragment` state, which is visible).

So, firstly your `savedInstaceState` is null, when the screen rotates, instances are saved and then restored on the `onCreate(savedInstanceState)` so it is not null anymore and anything inside `if(savedInstanceState == null)` will be called, and then you get the `NullPointerException`.

To fix the problem, remove this validation:

```
if(savedInstanceState == null){

    ///blablalba

}
```

Comment: no that's not it at all.. I don't want to display a new dialog I want the previous one to be restored. I figured this out actually I just haven't submitted the answer yet. I have to create the dialog in onCreateDialog of the DialogFragment. The instance I pass to the dialog seems to cause the problem. Not sure exactly why though.

Comment: @MattWolfe you should work with the previous dialog state inside your MyDialogFragment class, not on Activity class, had you tried it?