# DialogFragment mysterious Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, fragment, android-dialogfragment

I cannot seem to make head or tail from the stack trace eclipse is giving me. The code used to work. I am not sure what I changed. But now when I launch the dialog fragment, the app crashes with the following error log.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.company.appname, PID: 8962
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onActivityCreated(DialogFragment.java:366)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1508)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:958)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code is massive so I am not sure which portion to show. So maybe someone has seen this mysterious kind of crash with apparently no root in my code (i.e. since eclipse is not naming one)

**UPDATE**

Ok. I find the culprit. But I still don’t know how to fix it. So I have CatDialog (the one that’s crashing now) and FacebookDialog. So I have had these two DialogFragments working independently. But now I am launching `FacebookDialog` from inside the `onCreateView` method of the CatDialog. That is the reason for the crash. The launching is conditional as the following code shows

```
protected void requestFaceBookPublishPermission() {
        Log.i(TAG, "going into requestFaceBookPublishPermission");
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null || !session.isOpened() ||
            !session.isPermissionGranted(FacebookDialog.PERMISSION)) {
            FacebookDialog fb = new FacebookDialog();
            fb.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "fb");
            dismiss();
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "leaving requestFaceBookPublishPermission");

    }
```

Comment: DialogFragment.java:366 - this is the portion to show.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DialogFragment : NullPointerException (support library)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265611/dialogfragment-nullpointerexception-support-library)

Comment: I don't have a line 366.

Comment: @patrick thanks for the link. But I have never created a DialogFragment with a `dialog` variable. So here too I don't have one. Where would I create it in the first place so that it might be null inside `onCreateDialog`?

Comment: @KatedralPillon: I think it's rather that some dialog fragment is initialized incorrect somewhere in your code that may cause the error. Can you perhaps limit the problem to some action that you perform, or *some* place in your code? Otherwise it might be difficult to help.

Comment: If you look at the code at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.java#290 you'll see that mDialog is only instantiated once, in getLayoutInflater, perhaps you can figure something out from that?

Comment: First, make sure that you are on the latest Android Support package. I agree with Patrick, that your most likely problem is that `mDialog` is `null`, as there is just not that much stuff in `onActivityCreated()` that could directly generate a `NullPointerException`. As Patrick notes, `mDialog` is initialized in `getLayoutInflater()`, which should be used as part of normal `Fragment` setup (e.g., in the call to your `onCreateView()` method). Somehow, it would appear that you are interfering with this.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `dismiss()` from inside `requestFaceBookPublishPermission` and that's totally wack! You can't do that if you are calling it from inside `onCreateView` of another DialogFragment. So you seed to keep the two separated again. But great question though.

So understand what you are doing: you are dismissing before returning the view inside `onCreateView`. You are pre-empting.

Comment: I remove the dismiss method and all goes back to normal. Might you know some way to get it to work together somehow? The issue is that if I have to go inside the if statement, then I no longer need the present DialogFragment and so want to get rid of it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this issue before. Then I was dismissing the dialog inside oncreateView and I was getting NullpointerException. Then I moved my code to dismiss the dialog to onResume() and the issue was fixed!

**Wrong**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false); 

if(something){

} else{
    dismiss(); //Dismissing dialog here gives NullpointerException
    }
}
return view;
```

**Correct**

```
 @Override
 public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

if(something){
    } else{
        dismiss(); 
        }
    }
```